# All rows are not getting imported to datatable using oledbconnection

Tags: c#, .net, oledbconnection

I am stucked up at this point. I searched alot on gooogle but didnot find anything.
My problem is:
I have an Excel file which i want to export to datatable and from datatable i want to save it to oracle DB.
Excel file contains multiple columns and each column consists of large data(approx 20000characters/numbers).
using oledbconnection,excel columns with such large data are not copied to datatble.(Small data columns gets copied).
Can anyone suggest workaround to my problem???
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any errors?  Also not 100% clear is a c# program reading the excel file and then putting the data in a database.

Comment: No,i am not receiving any errros.Simply record with large cell data is not populated in datatable.Cell is blank in datatable.

Answer (score 0):

- Check the dataypes and their length i.e nvarchar(3000)
- If that doesnt work, test with a small set of data maybe 5 rows, you should be able to see a trend there.
- Also check the data type of your application, sometimes for large number you may use long, or if they are large strings maybe use a stringbuilder to pass the data instead of just a string....

Comment: Thanks,for your reply. Long data is getting inserted in Oracle Db.But thats second step of my code.First is to get excel data in Datatable for which ia m using OledbConnection(http://codehill.com/2009/01/reading-excel-2003-and-2007-files-using-oledb/),which is not working for large cell data.I am not receiving any error,Simply records is not populated in datatable.